# how to install MAGMA? I `make install` is run well, but `make test` cause error

Tags: linux, g++, magma

I want to install MAGMA in a server(centos) in order to use the GEMM function.

**I have installed CUDA and MKL in this server before i install MAGMA, and i check both is run well by runing a cuBLAS example program and a MKL example program.**

Before i describe what i haved happened i must point it seem that **there is no fortran in this server**. So i install MAGMA by follows:

1. I move `make.inc-examples/make.inc.mkl-gcc` to `../make.inc`
2. I modify make.inc:

I commented out:

- FORT      = gfortran
- FFLAGS    = -O3 $(FPIC)          -DNDEBUG -DADD_ -Wall -Wno-unused-dummy-argument
- F90FLAGS  = -O3 $(FPIC)          -DNDEBUG -DADD_ -Wall -Wno-unused-dummy-argument -x f95-cpp-input

and remove `-lgfortran` in

- LIB       = -lmkl_gf_lp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm -lgfortran

and i also set `MKLROOT=/home/lixin/intel/mkl` and `CUDADIR=/usr/local/cuda` in this file.

3. I run `make install prefix=/home/lixin/install/`, it seem well and i haven't see any error tag.
4. I run `make test`, it cause error soon:
   [image]

Comment: The test routine has a bug. Tell the developers, not us.

Comment: because i can't guarantee the install is absolutely no problem even i don't see any error tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out this is a bug in testing program.Thank for @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams point to this.
I have post this problem in MAGMA Forum, then i got a fix tar file, and this problem had solved.
If you also meet this problem, you can see [this post](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1774)